# how to stop R code if dataframe has 0 obersvations then stop execution

Tags: r, dataframe

I hav lots of exam data that am cleaning but some of the data after being processed has zero obs, I have written this code in a function & am calling the function in a loop so if any 1 file has zero observation @ check7 data-frame how can i code to stop the ongoing code execution & how can i directly display only the roll.number and score=0 of the current student roll.number without there being a error 'Error in aggregate.data.frame that no rows to aggregate'   any help is appreciated...

it should display

```
Roll.number  Score
602200166      0
```

Comment: better to handle your errors with `tryCatch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `stop` function. Add the following beneath check7:

```
 if(nrow(check7) == 0L) stop('Error in aggregate.data.frame that no rows to aggregate')
```

Since you say that you are running a loop, you could also add the iteration into the message using `paste`. Let's say your loop iterator variable was "i." You could then print the iteration as follows:

```
if(nrow(check7) == 0L) stop(paste("Error in aggregate.data.frame", i, "no rows to aggregate")
```

If the error is occurring at the final line, i.e., the creation of the total object, you could put the following to print out which iteration is creating the problem:

```
cat("we have reached test number", i, "at this point")
```

This will print every iteration until the error occurs, which will let you figure out what test is causing the problem.